# Rust Cargo CMake Integration with C++ Library Dependencies

Tags: c++, rust, rust-cargo

Let us say that I have Rust project that wants to use a `CMake` based C++
library. For that, I use a `build.rs` script something like below that uses the
`cmake` and `cxx` packages to build an external project (`spikes`):

```
let path = PathBuf::from(env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap());
let external = path.join("external");
let spikes = external.join("spikes");
if spikes.exists()
{
    println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=spikes");
    let ccl_includes = spikes.join("src");
    let dst = cmake::Config::new(spikes).build();
    let lib = "spikes_common";
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}/lib/spikes", dst.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static={}", lib);

    // Attempt to build the C++-bridge.
    cxx_build::bridge("src/imageio_cxx.rs")
        .file("external/imageio-bridge.cpp")
        .include(spikes_includes)
        .flag_if_supported("-std=c++17")
        .compile("libimageio-bridge");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=external/imageio-bridge.h");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=external/imageio-bridge.cpp");
}
```

This works fine for the most part, but I can't seem to find any documentation on
how to handle link dependencies from the C++ project. E.g., in the above example
the C++ library uses `OpenEXR`, but naturally, the linker flags are not
propagated to the Rust project, making it fail during the compilation linking
step. What is the current best practice for propagating linker flags from a C++
project to `Cargo`?

Comment: Do you mean, automatically, or manually?

Comment: As automatic as possible, especially since the example above already contains an example for linking a library manually (`println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static={}", lib);`)

Answer (score 2):

So based on what I've read about this cargo crate I can forsee 3 options:

- You scrape the cmake files for the appropriate flags construct a string slice and pass it to the bridge
- You manually type them out
- Or this hackish solution: via `pkg-config` if applicable pkg-config just pastes out what you specify to paste out.

If you go with option 3 you have then two options on how to get it in

1. I don't see under the hood of cxx.rs, but perhaps you could pass it to the `flags_if_possible` - I've done similar hacks before in qmake.
2. You could just execute the command, grab the output and create a string slice that you input into the same method.

Hope it helps!

EDIT: If there is a cmake file then IIRC cmake has a feature to generate pkg-config files from its targets.

Comment: This seems to be roughly what I expected. You don't happen to have any links for pkg-config generation? The best I found was https://www.scivision.dev/cmake-generate-pkg-config/ which clearly isn't official

Comment: I've checked the site that you posted and the tutorial seems legit. I vaguely remember having to do it through [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html). As your link shows you do have to create the `.pc.in` file if it doesn't exist. However as you can see from the provided example it is just a few lines where you specify to cmake where it is supposed to populate target variables. The concepts for creating `.pc.in` are the same as for for `cmake.in`, which I will append a link to in the next comment.

Comment: [How to generate cmake find project files](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-to-create-a-ProjectConfig.cmake-file). EDIT: Just to add a last footnote, you don't have to rely on pkg-config, you can in the same way populate any text file and use it for your project. CMake itself is doing this when it is generating the makefile via `cmake -B ... -S ...` command. If you're on linux you could `find / grep` through the generated files and extract using regex. On windows PS you could use the `Select-String` cmdlet